# Why does a scrollbar appear in chrome display distorting my CSS but NOT in Chrome's Development Tools virtual display?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, scrollbar, display

Issue: Two html elements, each with a width 50vw and placed side-by-side, occupy 100% of chromes virtual viewport width in development tool (as you might expect!), but NOT in chromes full screen mode. they are stacked on top of each other and a scroll-bar appears at the right-hand side. Its the same with Firefox or Chrome. Check my code because I don't see the error..

Setting: body {overflow: hidden;} resolves the issue (by force) but prevents scrolling, or reducing the height to 100px resolves the issue which isn't practical (this part is really confusing me). However, these are not viable solutions for my web application project as you might understand.

It appears that chrome is adding a scrollbar that is not required but that doesn't make sense to me. Please help. I don't know how to fix this. Its like the browser is calculating if a scroll would be necessary if the elements were stacked and if 'true', it adds a scroll-bar even though the elements were not originally stacked. This calculation happens in the full-screen browser but not in dev. tools virtual display. This is what it appears to be doing but I don't understand it.

edit: I discovered that using two 50% elements instead of two 50vw elements resolves this issue. If anyone knows why, I would appreciate your insights.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    overflow: ; /*overflow: hidden resolves the issue. */
  }
  #leftSect {
    margin: 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 400px; /*height: 100px resolves the issue*/
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  #rightSect {
    margin: 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 400px; /*height: 100px resolves the issue*/
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<section id = "leftSect">
</section>
<section id = "rightSect">
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What OS are you on and what Browser Version do you use? I can not reproduce this on Chrome Version 116.0.5845.187 on MacOS

Comment: I'm using Windows-10 Pro, Chrome Version 116.0.5845.188 (Official Build) (64-bit).